# How do i pull out unique values that are in one column but not another? Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Looking for advice on how to pull out unique values that occur in one column but not another. I have them highlighted using conditional formatting which seems to be correct and work well, however the list is loooong so I would like to have another column that simply lists the names that are appear in one column but not the other.

For example:

ListA:
Steve
Sean
Simon
Lewis
Lewis
Ray

List B:
Sam
Steve
Gary
Paul
Lewis
Simon

If I run it on the two columns above the final column should simply list Sam, Gary and Paul from ListB as they do not appear in ListA.

I have tried using vlookup etc,. but for someone reason I get a different outcome from the Conditional Formatting (the latter of which gives the correct output).

Answer (score 2):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this function:

```
=FILTER(B1:B6,ISERROR(MATCH(B1:B6,A1:A5,0)))
```

Comment: Wrapped in unique if there could be duplicates